# "Bona fide" vs "Bonafide"

Tags: confusables

Simply put - is it correct to use "Bonafide" instead of "bona fide" (with the space)?

I'm planning to name a product, and wondering if I could use the single word and still be correct.

Comment: There is no "correct" or "incorrect" when it comes to product names. (Well, there are laws against trademark and copyright infringement.)

Comment: See http://www.bonafiderocks.com/

Comment: @Drew - agreed. I meant from the users' perspective - how they would think of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘wondering if I could use the single word and still be correct’

No.  *Bona fide* is two words, so ‘the single word’ simply is *not* ‘correct’.

In branding a product, you may reasonably experiment with any (not-illegal) expression you like.  You are free to invent the word ‘bonafide’ if you wish.

It seems to me, however, that compressing *bona fide* into a single word would be something of a hostage to fortune since the words literally mean ‘in good faith’, and are generally used to indicate reliability.

oxforddictionaries also gives an [adverbial definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bona-fide) of ‘Without intention to deceive’.

With that kind of sentiment in mind, it would seem safer to keep the two words as they are.  Mangling them could easily be regarded as either willful artifice or blatant ignorance, neither of which would help your marketing.

Comment: I see *bonafide* as an adjective and adverb in the Google definition (Oxford dictionaries) without any labels, although the examples they have retain the space.